# Submit form on change of dropdown list in Semantic UI?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, submit, form-submit, semantic-ui

I would like to submit form when an element is selected - skipping pressing the submit button.

[image]

I tried using `onchange="this.form.submit()"`, but it's not working here.

This is the code:

```
<form action="" method="get">

    <div class="ui floating dropdown labeled search icon button dd">
        <input type="hidden" name="nutr_code">
        <span class="text">Select nutrient</span>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" data-value="ca">Calcium</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="fe">Iron</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="mg">Magnesium</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="zn">Zinc</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Show results">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using GET method you can redirect with javascript by constructing the url yourself.

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
'onChange': function (value, text, $choice) {
    location.href = 'http://example.com/?nutr_code=' + value;
}});
```

---

Second option is changing the input field 'nutr_code' with the value from the callback as shown above

```
$('input[name="nutr_code"]').val(value);
```

and submit the `<FORM/>` from js.

```
$('form').submit();
```

EDIT:
Example of second option.

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
'onChange': function (value, text, $choice) {
    // Uncomment if semantic is not updating the input before submit.
    //$('input[name="nutr_code"]').val(value);
    $('form').submit();
}});
```

Comment: You're awesome, thank you! The second option is the one I used. Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define action in form tag or add some method to submit button

```
 <input type="submit" value="Show results" onclick="someFunction()">
```

You need to define someFunction() too if you follow this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[name='nutr_code']").on('input',function(e){
        $("input[type='submit']").trigger( "click" );
    });
  });
```